# generate-id generates different ids on same nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I experienced a strange behaviour of the saxon XSLT processor which I don't know whether it's a bug or a feature: generate-id() does not generate the same ID on identical nodes. (To make things clear, I use a very short transformation stylesheet. One can achieve the same output in a simpler way, but then we don't see the effect.)

The input XML is as simple as follows:

```
<list>
<entry>beta</entry>
<entry>gamma</entry>
<entry>alpha</entry>
</list>
```

This input is transformed by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>

      <xsl:call-template name="mkIndex">
        <xsl:with-param name="rootParam" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <a id="{generate-id(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="mkIndex">
    <xsl:param name="rootParam"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rootVar">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- use $rootParam here to get the correct IDs with generate-id()-->
    <xsl:for-each select="$rootVar//entry">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
      <a href="#{generate-id(.)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
      </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Using this stylesheet all IDs generated in `mkIndex` start with `d2` while the "basic" IDs start with `d1`.

If you use the variable `$rootParam` instead of `$rootVar` the IDs generated in `mkIndex` look the same as the "basic" IDs. Texts are the same in both cases, therefore we handle the same nodes in both cases.

I don't understand why identical nodes get different IDs with generate-id(). Maybe someone can explain the difference.

Thank you,

leu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well with the code

```
<xsl:variable name="rootVar">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>
```

you create a temporary tree with new nodes (which are deep copies of the ones in the input tree but are not identical to them).

So change that code to

```
<xsl:variable name="rootVar" select="."/>
```

if you want to work with the nodes in the input tree.